# Matrix report - Page breaks for each column group

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2005, ssrs-grouping, page-break

I'm using VS2005 to create my reports.

I have a matrix report that works beatifully.  I have country going down on the left hand side (row group called "matrix1_country_name") and data going across for 2 column groups, product_node and month (column groups "matrix1_Node" and "matrix1_calendar_month_name" respectively)

The only thing I want to improve is that this report will always show 5 year/60 months of data, and with multiple nodes I'd rather have each node be on its own page (Ideally I'd love to have it on the same page but in the rows just below to first node, but I'm not sure that's even possible).

I've seen numerous responses on these boards about putting in page breaks on column groups, but I can't seem to find how to do that in VS2005.  The examples I've read that can do that seem to have a different interface so I'm guessing they aren't in VS2005.

Does VS2005 allow you to add page breaks after each group item and I'm just missing it?  Or is there a trick I can do to get that to happen?  I've also read about nestin matrix reports in list reports but that seems more complicated than doing the page break on the column group, so I'd rather do the easiest solution if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see pagebreaks are ignored on column_groups.  Well I guess I'll try one of these workarounds.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ea9d795b-8d17-41d2-a1d7-a4069ebb4539

Comment: Has anyone ever done any of these workarounds?  I'm trying and not getting the expected results.